# Are the section titles customizable

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, administration, sitepages, collapsible-sections

I use Sharepoint modern experience site with collapsible sections.

Are the titles of the sections customizable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no SharePoint default settings available to customize the collapsible section titles.

So, you cannot change the font size, font family or font color of the section display name.

**Source**: [SharePoint: Collapsible sections on modern pages](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/07/01/sharepoint-collapsible-sections-on-modern-pages/)

Comment: Agreed with Ganesh, currently, we just could change the text of the title of collapsible section, no settings to change the font size, font family or font color. For this request, you can submit a feedback on https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472